# \printindex causes error in TikZ externalization

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-external, imakeidx

I've managed to trim down the example to just this:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale} % not really needed, but I do `\includegraphics{some.tikz} in my doc,
                       % so just you know I'm interested in that to work,
                       % if you think it's affected by the problem.
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=img/externalized/]

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (10pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Commenting out `\printindex` and changing something in the `tikzpicture` to trigger a regeneration of the PDF, externalization works just fine.

Alternatively, commenting out `\tikzexternalize` makes things work to.

But having both `\tikzexternalize` and `\printindex`, and triggering a generation of a PDF from a `tikzpicture`/`\tikz`/similar, causes a failure in the externalization.

Obviously, I could do this (via a `Makefile`)

- comment `\printindex` out,
- compile, thus externalizing all TikZ graphics,
- uncomment `\printindex`,
- compile again,

but it sounds a bit weird.